# jQuery use .hasClass to run several different methods

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use `.hasClass` as a sort of *if statement*. By determining which class the clicked element has, I'm running several different methods.

If the span clicked has a class of `inactive` then I wish to:

1. Remove the class `inactive`
2. Add new class `active`
3. Make the next sibling div with class `definition` slide down (using `.next`)

And in the reverse, if the span clicked has a class of `active` then:

1. Remove the class `active`
2. Add class `inactive`
3. Make the next sibling div with class `definition` slide up.

Essentially I'm showing or hiding a certain element and adding some styling using the classnames.

Full JS Fiddle here:

**http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/9ms79uhe/3/**

I had it working OK just using `this` for the active class, but when I tried to add in `.hasClass` it stopped working. Am I using `.hasClass` incorrectly?

I get the error *undefined is not a function* on line 6, so the start of my `.hasClass` line.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$( "#jargon-main span" ).click(function() { 
    // if class = "active" then:
      // remove class active
      // add class inactive
      // make .next sibling with class .definition slideUp
    $(this).hasClass("active").removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').next(".definition").slideUp( "fast", function() {});

    // if class = "inactive" then:
        // remove class inactive
        // add class active
        // make .next sibling with class .definition slideDown
     $(this).hasClass("inactive").removeClass('inactive').addClass('active').next(".definition").slideDown( "fast", function() {});

});
```

Comment: `.hasClass` returns boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, jQuery's `hasClass` returns a boolean, it's either true or false, depending on wether or not the element has the class.

If you want to target only elements that has a certain class, you use it as a regular selector, or you use a condition

```
if ( $(this).hasClass("inactive") ) {
    $(this).removeClass('inactive')
           .addClass('active')
           .next(".definition")
           .slideDown( "fast", function() {});
}
```

There's also jQuery's `toggleClass` that will toggle the class automatically.

```
$(this).toggleClass('active inactive').next(".definition").slideToggle("fast");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ms79uhe/7/)

Comment: Thanks for this, and the extra tip. However I'm now getting a problem where it seems to be able to remove the "active" class resulting in the pane re-opening. Give it a test: http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/9ms79uhe/5/

Comment: Sorry, ignore above. I did not add ELSE to the second statement

Comment: @Francesca - That's where the beauty of the toggle methods come in -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9ms79uhe/6/**

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `$.hasClass` returns a Boolean(true or false). So you need a `if` condition

```
if($(this).hasClass("active")){
    $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').next(".definition").slideUp( "fast", function() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.hasClass() returns Boolean, so You can't call .removeClass() from result of .hasClass().

So working Js Fiddle will be:
http://jsfiddle.net/99qebvjr/1/

```
$( "#jargon-main span" ).click(function() { 
    // if class = "active" then:
      // remove class active
      // add class inactive
      // make .next sibling with class .definition slideUp
    if($(this).hasClass("active")){         
       $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').next(".definition").slideUp( "fast", function() {});
    }
    // if class = "inactive" then:
        // remove class inactive
        // add class active
        // make .next sibling with class .definition slideDown
    else if($(this).hasClass("inactive")){
      $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active').next(".definition").slideDown( "fast", function() {});
    }   
});
```